# Непонятное выражение sizeof(0)["\0"]

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, sizeof, выражение

Объясните, что означает это выражение и почему выводит единицу?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::cout << sizeof(0)["\0"] << '\n';   
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

sizeof это интересная штука и не то, чем кажется. Оно вычисляет значения выражения "виртуально", что бы узнать тип, а потом возвращает его значение. Давайте пошагово повторим за компайлером.

Исходное выражение

```
std::cout << sizeof(0)["\0"] << '\n';
```

Вначале добавим правильные скобки

```
std::cout << sizeof((0)["\0"]) << '\n';
```

А тут спрятана старая сишная истина - `a[b] == b[a] == *(a+b)`. Переставим.

```
std::cout << sizeof("\0"[0]) << '\n';
```

Теперь очевидно, что там просто один символ

```
std::cout << sizeof('\0') << '\n';
```

А `sizeof(char)` в плюсах - это всегда по правилам 1.

Comment: А почему `"\0"[0]` это `'\0'`, ведь `std::strlen("\0")` это `0`?

Comment: потому что `std::strlen("\0")` считает до нулевого символа, но его не учитывает. Вас же не удивляет, когда в си для выделения памяти под строку, говорят "и не забыть +1"?

Comment: Думаю ответ должен быть принят автором, вопроса(нажмите на галочку)

Comment: а можно на медальку особую заработать (там есть "ответ принят после многих плюсов спустя какое - то время)